# SAXON XSLT 3.0 unable to generate an xml:base attribute within generated <rdf:RDF /> output

Tags: rdf, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am using SAXON and an XSL 3.0 transform to generate an RDF file as my target output. Per the W3C RDF specification to properly resolve relative IRIs I need an **xml:base** URI specified in the generated <rdf:RDF /> header of the file.  I'm unable to generated this attribute with the appropriate xml: prefix.

I have the following sample.xml as input to my XSLT 3.0 transform:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog xmlns="http://langdale.com.au/2005/Message#"
         xmlns:m="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CPSM-ShortCircuit#"
         ontologyURI="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16"
         baseURI="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CPSM-ShortCircuit#"
         name="ShortCircuit">
   <Note>This profile represents the equipment of the power system and their hierarchical relationships.</Note>
   <ComplexType name="ACDCTerminal"
                baseClass="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#ACDCTerminal"
                package="Core"
                packageURI="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#Package_Core"
                minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <Comment>An electrical connection point (AC or DC) to a piece of conducting equipment.</Comment>
      <SuperType name="IdentifiedObject"
                 baseClass="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#IdentifiedObject"/>
   </ComplexType>
   
   <ComplexType name="IdentifiedObject"
                baseClass="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#IdentifiedObject"
                package="Core"
                packageURI="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#Package_Core"
                minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <Comment>This is a root class to provide common identification for all classes needing identification and naming attributes.</Comment>
      <Simple dataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
              xstype="string"
              name="mRID"
              baseProperty="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#IdentifiedObject.mRID"
              minOccurs="0"
              maxOccurs="1">
         <Comment>Master resource identifier issued by a model authority.</Comment>
      </Simple>
   </ComplexType>
   
</Catalog>
```

The XSLT 3.0 transform being applied is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="a" version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:cims="http://iec.ch/TC57/1999/rdf-schema-extensions-19990926#" 
    xmlns:a="http://langdale.com.au/2005/Message#" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

    <xsl:output xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" />
    <!-- baseURI and ontologyURI parameters passed in. baseURI is for the profile and ontologyURI for the xml:base attribute -->
    <xsl:param name="baseURI"/>
    <xsl:param name="ontologyURI"/>
    <xsl:param name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="a:Catalog">
        <rdf:RDF xml:base="{$ontologyURI}">
            <xsl:variable name="rdf" as="node()*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:perform-sort select="$rdf">
                <xsl:sort select="@rdf:about"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- NOTE: remaining template definitions not needed for the example have been removed  -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which fails during execution with the below exception when I specify an **xml:base** attribute as indicated (i.e. `<rdf:RDF xml:base="{$ontologyURI}">`).

```java
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing http://langdale.com.au/2005/xsdgen: langdale.com.au
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:157)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.addStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:171)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.setStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:163)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.setStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:191)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.ProfileBuildlets$TransformBuildlet.build(ProfileBuildlets.java:243)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.ProfileBuildlets$ProfileBuildlet.run(ProfileBuildlets.java:143)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.CIMBuilder$Worker.run(CIMBuilder.java:221)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.CIMBuilder.build(CIMBuilder.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing http://langdale.com.au/2005/xsdgen: langdale.com.au
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:856)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:154)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing http://langdale.com.au/2005/xsdgen: langdale.com.au
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:467)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:168)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.sendStylesheetSource(StylesheetModule.java:157)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(StylesheetModule.java:229)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:113)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:851)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: langdale.com.au
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:561)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1233)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:439)
    ... 25 more
---------
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing http://langdale.com.au/2005/xsdgen: langdale.com.au
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:856)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:154)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.addStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:171)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.setStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:163)
    at au.com.langdale.profiles.ProfileSerializer.setStyleSheet(ProfileSerializer.java:191)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.ProfileBuildlets$TransformBuildlet.build(ProfileBuildlets.java:243)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.ProfileBuildlets$ProfileBuildlet.run(ProfileBuildlets.java:143)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.CIMBuilder$Worker.run(CIMBuilder.java:221)
    at au.com.langdale.cimtoole.builder.CIMBuilder.build(CIMBuilder.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing http://langdale.com.au/2005/xsdgen: langdale.com.au
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:467)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:168)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.sendStylesheetSource(StylesheetModule.java:157)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(StylesheetModule.java:229)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:113)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:851)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: langdale.com.au
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:613)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:561)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1233)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:439)
    ... 25 more
```

If I hardcode the value instead it generates successfully (i.e. hardcoded as `<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16">`) but I need to be able to programmaticaly pass in different base URIs.

When I leave the expression in place and remove the xml: prefix (i.e. `<rdf:RDF base="{$ontologyURI}">`) the XSLT then works with the RDF header output as shown below. However, per the W3C RDF spec I need the fully prefixed attribute (**xml:base**) for the baseURI for resolving relative IRIs.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF 
    xmlns:cims="http://iec.ch/TC57/1999/rdf-schema-extensions-19990926#" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    base="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16">
    
...
...
    
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Please don't tell us that it "fails during execution" without telling us HOW it fails. Knowing how it fails is surely where any attempt to solve the problem should start. OK, I can work it out, but why should I have to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `xml:base` in the stylesheet is being interpreted as a base attribute on the element on which it occurs. Like `xml:id` using it as a literal attribute places it's semantics on the element *in the stylesheet*.

You can avoid this with:

```
<rdf:RDF>
  <xsl:attribute name="xml:base" select="$ontologyURI"/>
  ...
```

Comment: For more information see also the note starting "The xml:base, xml:lang, xml:space, and xml:id attributes have two effects in XSLT. " in §11.1.2 of the XSLT 3.0 Recommendation.

Comment: @MichaelKay , thanks for pointing me to this documentation reference.